# Lowering Background Image of a Panel in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to build a piano and i have a panel that is designed to house the musical staffs as a background image of this panel.

I have tried to apply these as a Picture Box but this hindered a lot of my other features of this piano. These are the current settings that are related to this particular panel:

```
this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
this.Size = new Size(750, 75)
this.Location = new Point(125, 75);
this.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;

this.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\..\\Notes-Images\\Notes-Images\\staff2.bmp");

this.Visible = true;
```

I need to find a way how to actually have control on the location of where the background image is placed so as to lower it from the top left of the panel

Comment: Don't use the BackgroundImage property.  Just use the OnPaint override and paint it where you want it.

Comment: Use a second panel containing the image and move this panel to where you need the image.

Comment: Are you really _"trying to build a piano"_?

Comment: @LarsTech thanks, that did the trick! Happy Holidays :)